# Why is my image not filled with green?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

i've seen a similar question, but i didn't get a proper solution, so here's my problem:
([Coloring an area of BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671551/coloring-an-area-of-bufferedimage))

i'm creating a BufferedImage, then i grab the graphics from this image, i'll paint a green rectangle on it and let it show within a JPanel...  but surprise - it's not green, wo where is my error??

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ViewPortTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ViewPortTest().startUp();
    }


    private void startUp() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);        
        frame.add(new TestPanel() );
        frame.pack();       
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class TestPanel extends JPanel{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private int myWidth = 256;
        private int myHeight = 156;     
        private BufferedImage img;      

        public TestPanel() {
            super();        
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(myWidth, myHeight) );            
            img = new BufferedImage(myWidth, myHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
            img.createGraphics();                   
            img.getGraphics().setColor(Color.GREEN);
            img.getGraphics().fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);         
            img.getGraphics().dispose();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (img != null ){
                g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

what comes out is this:

[image: not green screen]

so - where is my green rectangle???

Comment: Why do you `dispose()` the Graphics ? You still need it on painting.

Comment: Hi Peter, it won't make any difference - i read about that 'hint' to dispose the graphics in another SOF-article , but it won't make any difference, have a try on your own...

Comment: Overriding `paintComponent` is not a good idea. May help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544549/how-does-paintcomponent-work

Comment: Hi Peter, the image is drawn indeed, it's not a matter of repaint... but it's white colored not green....

Comment: Hi Peter, it makes no difference if you paintComponent(Graphics gr) or simply paint(Graphics gr)

Comment: Hello Peter, thanks again for bringing in so much passion... even if you may not have helped me directly, you provided aid when it was required!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the multiple calls to `getGraphics()`. It is creating multiple `Graphics` objects. This is essentially an alias for `createGraphics()`. See [BufferedImage#getGraphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getGraphics()). A simple fix would be to store the `Graphics2D` object created by calling `createGraphics()` and make all of your calls on that object:

```
Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();                   
g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
g.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);         
g.dispose();
```

Comment: so i'm very confused - what's the purpose of createGraphics() and getGraphics()  maybe you can add a slight explanation on why my Graphics would be reCreated every time i ask for it?

Comment: The docs explain the reasoning for `getGraphics`, it's basically there for backwards compatibility. It was also a poor name for a method because it doesn't return the same object every time it is called (Thus your confusion). Basically, you can treat it as deprecated, since `createGraphics` provides a better interface and is more explicitly named.

Comment: a @depricated would have helped me very much...   thanks again for that explanation and thanks, that you do have the same understanding for getter/setter...

Answer (score 1):

Because `createGraphics()` always returns a new `Graphics2D` context. So you set the green color on one context, and you fill a rectange using another which does not know about the green color you set on another context.

Try this:

```
Graphics2d g = img.createGraphics();                   
g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
g.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);         
g.dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple problem with `Graphics` instance:

```
  Graphics2D createGraphics = img.createGraphics();                   
  createGraphics.setColor(Color.GREEN);
  createGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);         
  createGraphics.dispose();
```